# Characters not escaped properly when passing to dictionary

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, escaping

Before this is marked as a duplicate, the other question with a similar name is pertinent to regex and is different from my problem.

I have the string

```
Principal = "{\"id\":\"number\"}"
```

If I am not mistaken this should escape to `{"id":"number"}`.

However, when I pass it to the following method

```
Dictionary<string, object> folder = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            folder.Add("Principal", Principal);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(folder);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
```

It returns as

```
{
"Principal":"{\"id\":\"number\"}"
}
```

Ideally I would like it to return

```
{
"Principal":{"id":"number"}
}
```

Why is it holding on to the quotes and escape characters? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Principal is a string, and so gets escaped as one.

If you want to escape it as an JSON object, it needs to be an object in your application as well.

If you also want to deserialize it or use it more than once, I propose to define your object in a class. If not, you can just use an anonymous object :

```
Dictionary<string, object> folder = new Dictionary<string, object>();
folder.Add("Principal", new { id = "number" });
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(folder);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

/edit: And here is it with a non-anonymous class:

Class definition:

```
class Principal
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
Dictionary<string, object> folder = new Dictionary<string, object>();
folder.Add("Principal", new Principal(){ id = "number" });
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(folder);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! My code's still not working but this part is thanks to you!

Answer (score 3):

One option to add to @Compufreak's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43239621/3744182).

Your call to [`JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm) indicates you are already using [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net).  If you have a pre-serialized JSON literal string that you need to include as-is without escaping in some container POCO when the container is serialized, you can wrap the string in a [`JRaw`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JRaw.htm) object:

```
 folder.Add("Principal", new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JRaw(Principal));
```

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` will subsequently emit the JSON string without escaping.  Of course, the `Principal` string needs to be *valid* JSON, otherwise the resulting serialization will be bad.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cQIdv8).